# An efficient way of converting a vector of characters into integers based on frequency in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a vector of characters consisting of only 'a' or 'g', I want to convert them to integers based on frequency, i.e. the more frequent one should be coded to 0, and the other to 1, for example:

```
set.seed(17)
x = sample(c('g', 'a'), 10, replace=T)
x
# [1] "g" "a" "g" "a" "g" "a" "g" "g" "a" "g"
x[x == names(which.max(table(x)))] = 0
x[x != 0] = 1
x
# [1] "0" "1" "0" "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "1" "0"
```

This works, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do it.

(We don't have to consider the 50%-50% case here, because it should never happen in our study.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
ag.encode <- function(x)
{
  result <- x == "a"
  if( sum(result) > length(result) %/% 2 ) 1-result else as.numeric(result)
}
```

If you want to keep the labels in a `factor` structure, use this instead:

```
ag.encode2factor <- function(x)
{
  result <- x == "a"
  if( sum(result) > length(result) %/% 2 )
  {
     factor(2-result, labels=c("a","g"))
  }
  else
  {
     factor(result+1, labels=c("g","a"))
  }
}
```

Comment: It's indeed faster this way. Why?

Comment: `%chin%` (only for character vectors) from `data.table` is faster than `%in%` and `==`. So, doing `x %chin% "a"` should make it a tad bit faster.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your character vector to a `factor` one. This solution is more general in the sense you don't need to know the name of the 2 characters used to create x.

```
y <- as.integer(factor(x))-1
if(sum(y)>length(y)/2) y <- as.integer(!y)
```

Comment: This one is slower than @Ferdinand.kraft 's solution, but is still faster than mine. Thanks.

Comment: Prefer `factor(x, levels = names(sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)))) - 1L`. Will work with any number of levels.

Comment: @flodel what benefits will `1L` bring compared to just `1`? I see this a lot in core R functions.

Comment: @flodel There is an extra parenthesis in your comment. Also it gives a warning message and the result is a vector of NAs

Comment: It should be `as.integer(factor(x, levels = names(sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)))) - 1L`. `as.integer` returns an `integer` vector, so you want to subtract `1L` (an integer) and not `1` (a numeric) to retain an `integer` vector. Using integers and not numerics when you mean it can be benefitial in many ways. Integers use less memory, some operations using them are a lot faster, and they are more robust as they are not subject to floating point issues.